# How do I target a div that comes directly after another div and they're both within the same parent div?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to use CSS to target only the `.goodbye` that comes after `.hello`?

```
<div>
    <div class="hello"></div>
    <div class="goodbye"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="hola"></div>
    <div class="goodbye"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="anyoung"></div>
    <div class="goodbye"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [adjusting sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) selector

```
.hello + .goodbye {}
```

This selector will select only those `.goodbye` that *immediately* follow the `.hello` element. Depending on what you need you can also use [general sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/general_sibling_selectors) selector, like demonstated in Mary Melody answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by using the CSS `~` general sibling selectors like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mz631vv3/)**

```
.hello ~ .goodbye {
    color:red;
}
```

> *The `~` combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent. - [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)*

CSS `~` general sibling selector target all `.goodbye` that comes after `.hello` within the same parent div.

**For Example:** JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4L4kbar9/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.hello + .goodbye {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way

```
.hello + .goodbye { 
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

The element+element selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.